# Display (loading) message while fetching geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I want to give the user a message when fetching his/her position with getCurrentPostion(), when he/she has given the permission to share the location. As you could see from the basic code structure below, it's too late to put the message in the successHandler since we have the position by then.

However, it's to early to put it when calling getCurrentPostion() because the user have not accepted (or denied) permission yet.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successHandler, errorHandler);

function errorHandler(error) {
    if ( error.code === error.PERMISSION_DENIED ) {
        *display error message*
    }
}

function successHandler() {
    if ( PERMISSION_ACCEPTED )
        *display fetching position message*
}
```

Is it possible to display a "Fetching position, please wait" the moment the user gives permission to share his/her location?

Answer (score 0):

You should post up your "please wait" message before calling getCurrentPosition. Your error and success handlers can then remove the message.

Comment: No, it's then displayed before the user has decided to give (or not to give) permission.

Comment: My mistake. The geolocation api doesn't provide hooks for the consent / decline event, so I think you might be out of luck. It might be worth showing the message before the user gives consent anyway; it provides enforcement to the user that something is expected of them.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it seems like that. Thanks for your time though. I currently do as you suggest and display the loading message before he/she gives permission and it works ok (not perfect though :) )